# Bringing cooked meat to Germany?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany

I know it is prohibited to bring meat or dairy products to Germany,
but I wonder if bringing cooked meat would also be a problem? It is
part of our curries and other material in the curry are beans and 
vegetables so the only problem is the cooked meat. Does anybody have
any exact information?

Here is a link that gives information about fresh meat. But I don't know
wether it applies for cooked meat or not?!

http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/DE-Germany-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm

Comment: Where would you be coming from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the relevant information [from the German customs agency](https://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/Restrictions/Animals-and-plants-products-containing-animal-or-vegetable-substance/Protection-against-animal-diseases/Provisions-on-the-import-of-animal-products/provisions-on-the-import-of-animal-products_node.html):

> When meat or milk, or meat or dairy products such as sausage or cheese
>   are imported for personal consumption they must meet the same
>   veterinary requirements as those applying to commercial imports.
>
> This means that travellers who are carrying such products may only
>   enter the European Union through those points of entry where a
>   veterinarian is on duty. The necessary health certificates and a
>   validated Common Veterinary Entry Document - CVED must also accompany
>   the products.

Sounds like a lot of hassle... Maybe you can find deli stores in Germany that sell this cooked meat the way you need it?

Answer (score 5):

It depends if you enter Germany from an EU country or from a third country.

In the first case there is no problem as long as the meat is for personal consumption. This also applies for products from  Switzerland, Liechtenstein, Norway, Andorra, and San Marino.

In the second case it is more difficult. Even if the meat is for personal consumption you have to go through a veterinary control. It does not matter if the meat is cooked or not.

http://www1.zoll.de/english_version/faq/a0_passenger_traffic/c0_prohibited_restricted_goods/index.html

Germany, just as all the other EU member states has to comply to the EU regulation 206/2009.

Comment: Yes, in theory, you're *supposed* to go through veterinary control.  In practice there is zero enforcement of this, and if even you were to ask the Customs guy "there's some meat in my curry here, can I bring it in", I suspect he would roll his eyes and wave you through -- it's not exactly the kind of biohazard the law is meant for.

Comment: @jpatokal: I think you underestimate the conscientiousness of German customs agents. I have seen several documentaries where airline passengers carrying meat and fish were stopped and severely reprimanded and fined.

Comment: I confirm and have seen it in real life. German customs officers are thorough and conscious.  If they discover whatsoever they won't content themselves with rolling eyes.

Comment: An obvious solution would be to enter the EU through another country and then proceed to Germany. Even a transit flight through another EU country should be enough to get you off the Customs radar. Though this is probably illegal.

Comment: @JonathanReez: it's not illegal, but at least in theory shouldn't make a difference since all EU contries have to implement the same measures.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt: theoretically, yes. Practically, some countries are most likely less stringent than Germany about their custom controls.

Answer (score 1):

For Bio-security reasons,i.e. disease control, most countries will not allow any kind of meat to be brought in, even if it is cooked.   I tried to bring some Swedish  bear sausage in to S. Korea,  customs took it. But, it might have something to do with bear being "good for man's power"