# Can I bring nuts and cooked sausage from Brazil to Germany?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany, food-and-drink, eu

Can I bring nuts from Brazil to Germany/Europe  and cooked sausage in my hand Bag? It is for personal use.

Comment: Do you plan on consuming them on the plane only or bringing them into Germany?

Comment: What sort of nuts? Commercially packaged ready-to-eat nuts are probably OK. The cooked sausage is probably not.

Comment: I would love to know why you want to import sausages *into* Germany. The other way around, ok, but *into* Germany? Must be some damn good sausages.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any restriction regarding nuts. For the sausage, it's slightly more complicated because animal products are [heavily regulated under EU law](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2009:077:0001:0019:EN:PDF).

A quick summary from the [Federal Ministry of Food and Agriculture's webpage](https://www.bmel.de/EN/Food/Safe-Food/_Texte/ErzeugnisseTierischenUrsprungs.html):

> In order to prevent the introduction of animal epidemics, **it is
>   prohibited to bring meat, milk and products derived therefrom into the
>   European Union from non-EU countries**.

[German customs provides slightly different information](https://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/Restrictions/Animals-and-plants-products-containing-animal-or-vegetable-substance/Protection-against-animal-diseases/Provisions-on-the-import-of-animal-products/provisions-on-the-import-of-animal-products_node.html):

> When meat or milk, or meat or dairy products **such as sausage** or cheese
>   are imported for personal consumption they **must meet the same
>   veterinary requirements as those applying to commercial imports.**
>
> This means that travellers who are carrying such products may only
>   enter the European Union through those points of entry where a
>   veterinarian is on duty. The necessary health certificates and a
>   validated Common Veterinary Entry Document - CVED must also accompany
>   the products.

So while according to the second source, it's technically possible to import meat there's [paperwork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Veterinary_Entry_Document) involved and you're restricted to [points of entry which are able to process it](https://ec.europa.eu/food/sites/food/files/animals/docs/bips_contact_germany.pdf).

How strictly this is enforced is, of course, a whole other conversation.

See also these related questions:

- [Bringing cooked meat to Germany](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23076/bringing-cooked-meat-to-germany)
- [Personal import of precooked bacon into Germany from USA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38385/personal-import-of-precooked-bacon-into-germany-from-usa)

Comment: Quite some hassle for a sausage ;-)